# Asymptote: draw surface from data points in 3D

Tags: diagrams, 3d, asymptote

In the figure below, you can see 25 curves. Each of these curves was plotted from a list of points in a file `mypoints_i.dat`. Each of these files contains the exact same number of points.

[image]

How would you draw the surface described by the curves? A solution was proposed [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118188/34258) with a triangulation technique, which is not required here since all the curves are drawn from the same number of points. Additionally,

- the color of the surface should shade from blue to red (as the curves below);
- the surface should be as smooth as possible.

**EDIT** I manage to plot the surface but I am not able to use the smoothening operator `operator..`, so the surface is very rough, see below. This is because I plot the plane quadrangles one by one. Of course I could refine the points but this would result in a heavy file, and resource-consuming 3D manipulations.

There must be a way to plot the surface smoothly, right?

Note that the surface actually corresponds to (half of) the curves above, even though it is not obvious.
[image]

The code for the surface is the following:

```
//////// SURFACE PART I ////////

int increment=1;
for (int i=1; i<51-increment; i=i+increment)
{
string filename1 = filebasename + string(i) + "PartI.dat";
string filename2 = filebasename + string(i+increment) + "PartI.dat";
file in1=input(filename1).line().csv();
file in2=input(filename2).line().csv();
real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
real[][] a2=in2.dimension(0,0);
a1=transpose(a1);
a2=transpose(a2);

real[] x=a1[0];
real[] y=a1[1];
real[] z=a1[3];

real[] x2=a2[0];
real[] y2=a2[1];
real[] z2=a2[3];

pen orbitpen=.7bp+red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50));
pen projpen=.3bp+red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50))+opacity(0.3);

int step=1;
for (int j=0; j<21-step; j=j+step) 
{
    path3 orbit1=graph(x,y,z,operator--);
    path3 orbit2=reverse(graph(x2,y2,z2));

    triple pointA1=(x[j],y[j],z[j]);
    triple pointA2=(x[j+step],y[j+step],z[j+step]);
    triple pointB1=(x2[j],y2[j],z2[j]);
    triple pointB2=(x2[j+step],y2[j+step],z2[j+step]);

    draw(surface(pointA1..pointA2--pointB2..pointB1--cycle),red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50))+opacity(1),currentlight);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2** Complete standalone example, including data files, available [here](http://www.filedropper.com/texse).

Comment: Could you sort all your points from farthest to closest to the POV?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I would probably be able to do so for _one_ POV, but I want to be able to manipulate my 3D object, in 3D within a pdf file (with prc). What do you have in mind? (BTW, I'm working on it, I add some elements to my post in a few hours.)

Comment: Never mind.  Smoothing is the issue now.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164509/484 for an Asymptote solution to a similar problem.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thank you, I was hoping you'd come over this post. I started studying your code, it seems to me the drawing is viewport-depending, right? That means it would not give a proper rendering with PRC?

Comment: @anderstood: The viewpoint-dependent code involves using some tricks to get semi-transparent surfaces to look good. If you are satisfied for all your surfaces to be opaque, this won't be an issue. Look, specifically, at how the surfaces `tempEllipsoid` and `ellipsoid` are constructed. The construction is viewpoint-independent. Only afterwards do I eliminate the portion facing away from the viewer--a step you can safely skip if you want opaque surfaces.

Comment: One more note: You want to look at the second, "more elaborate" example, not the first.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I now understand your code, except the details of the last part, which seem to rely on cyclicity. I hope the technique can be extended to open surfaces: I'll try and will update if I have the solution, or more likely, questions.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I did not manage to adapt your code to my open surface, so I defined `triple g(pair uv) { return tempsurface.point(uv.x, uv.y); }` where `tempsurface` is my non-smooth surface. Then I copy your `ellipsoid` function and play with the 2 pairs but the output is completely incomprehensible to me: I yields a tiny surface (compared to `tempsurface`) which does not correspond to the zone delimited by the 2 pairs.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Could you explain what `.point` returns? I don't understand why when I defined `triple g(pair uv) { return tempsurface.point(uv.x, uv.y); }`, `g((0,0))` (for example) returns a triple which has nothing to do with (0,0,"tempsurface((0,0))").

Comment: @anderstood: If `s` was a surface created by graphing a function or a parametric function, then `s.point` gives a parametrization of the surface. For instance, `s.point((0,0))` should give one of the four corners; and if the patches form (say) an `8 x 8` grid, then the opposite corner is given (roughly) by `s.point((7.9999, 7.9999))`. However, *if the surface is constructed by some means other than graphing function(s), then `s.point` returns nonsense*.

Comment: Is there a way to get the data files? The link above doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: @mac I don't have them available presently. From looking to the code I think each lines comprises x y z coordinates (possibly separated with tabs).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I thought about it some more and managed a considerable simplification. Both this solution and the previous operate on the same principle suggested by the user Symbol 1: If you look under the hood at the operation of the smooth surface grapher, it actually plots only those points on a rectangular grid in uv-space. So, even if you have only those points (say, given in a matrix of `triple`s), you can "trick" the grapher into believing you have a complete function--it will never know the difference, because it will only ever evaluate the function at the grid points. I believe this is also what O.G.'s "short solution" does.

Much of my previous solution was designed to figure out how to combine "rectangular" patches given in an arbitrary order. But since the points here are given in a regular order, that was overkill. (I mostly wrote it that way since I had already written the code, and the OP had already arranged the grid in rectangular patches in his/her own code.)

A note on the color palette: The `draw` method, when passed an array of pens, will arrange the "rectangular" patches in a regular (predictable) order and draw the first patch with the first pen, the second patch with the second pen, etc. So, technically, what is being drawn in this picture is not a smooth gradient; but in this particular example, it's close enough. By contrast, the `surface.colors()` method used in the answers of Symbol 1 and of O.G. colors the vertices rather than the patches (allowing for a smooth gradient, although not in `prc`) and stores this information in the `surface` object itself.

```
// Global Asymptote definitions can be put here.
import three;
import grid3;

usepackage("mathptmx");

// One can globally override the default toolbar settings here:
// settings.toolbar=true;

import graph3;

real xmin=-2, xmax=2;
real ymin=-2, ymax=1.5;
real zmin=-2.5, zmax=2.5;

limits((xmin,ymin,zmin),(xmax,ymax,zmax));

currentprojection=perspective(camera=(1.5,2,2.5));

unitsize(3cm,3cm,2cm);


real linewidth=1.1;
real linewidthprojections=.15;

string filebasename="./data/ForASY_mnl2ippGridBranche3T1_";

bool renderPRC = false;

if(renderPRC) {
    // PRC TRUE
    settings.prc=true;
    settings.embed=true;
}
else {
    // RASTERIZE
    settings.outformat="png";
    settings.prc=false;
    settings.render=3;
}

/////// ORBITS IN 3D, SMOOTH ////////
for (int i=1; i<=50; i=i+2)
{
    string filename1 = filebasename + string(i) + "PartI.dat";
    file in1=input(filename1).line().csv();
    real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
    a1=transpose(a1);

    real[] x1=a1[0];
    real[] y1=a1[1];
    real[] z1=a1[3];

    pen orbitpen=.7bp+red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50));
    pen projpen=.3bp+red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50))+opacity(0.3);

    path3 thepath1 = graph(x1, y1, z1, operator..);
    draw(thepath1,orbitpen,currentlight);
}



//////// SURFACE PART I ////////

surface smoothSurface(triple[][] points) {
  int nu = points.length - 1;
  if (nu <= 0) abort("Grid must have at least two rows to produce a surface.");
  int nv = points[0].length - 1;
  if (nv <= 0) abort("Grid must have at least two columns to produce a surface.");
  // Create a parametric function that is designed specifically for integer values.
  triple f(pair uv) { return points[floor(uv.x)][floor(uv.y)]; }
  // Now graph that parametric function:
  return surface(f, (0,0), (nu, nv),
                nu=nu, nv=nv,
                usplinetype=Spline, vsplinetype=Spline);
}

int increment=1;

material[] surfacecolors = new material[0];

triple[][] points = new triple[0][0];

for (int i=1; i<51; i=i+increment)
{
    string filename1 = filebasename + string(i) + "PartI.dat";
    file in1=input(filename1).line().csv();
    real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 means up to the end of the file
    a1=transpose(a1);

    real[] x=a1[0];
    real[] y=a1[1];
    real[] z=a1[3];

    triple[] currentrow = new triple[0];
    int step = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 21; j += step) {
            currentrow.push((x[j],y[j],z[j]));

        // Remember the color in which this patch should be drawn.
        if (i < 51-increment && j < 21-step)
          surfacecolors.push(
             red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50)) + rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50)) + opacity(1));
    }
    points.push(currentrow);
}


surface smoothsurface = smoothSurface(points);

draw(smoothsurface, surfacecolors);

////// CONTOUR OPENING //////

string fileImpactData = "./data/impactData.dat";
file in1=input(fileImpactData).line().csv();
real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
a1=transpose(a1);

real[] x1=a1[0];
real[] y1=a1[1];
real[] z1=a1[3];

pen contourpen=green+1.5bp;

draw(graph(x1,y1,z1,operator--),contourpen,currentlight);

////// PLANES ///////
pen bg=gray(0.9)+opacity(0.2);
draw(surface((xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmin,ymax,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmax,ymax,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmin)--cycle),bg);

////// GRID LINES ///////
pen gridpen=.2bp+gray(0.7);

grid3(XYgrid,Step=1,gridpen);
grid3(YXgrid,Step=.5,gridpen);
grid3(XZgrid,Step=1,gridpen);
grid3(ZXgrid,Step=2,gridpen);
grid3(YZgrid,Step=.5,gridpen);
grid3(ZYgrid,Step=2,gridpen);

// No-go zone
draw((xmax,1,zmin)--(xmin,1,zmin)--(xmin,1,zmax),black+1bp);

xaxis3(Label("$x_1$",MidPoint,align=Y-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
yaxis3(Label("$x_2$",MidPoint,align=X-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=.5),p=black);
zaxis3(Label("$\dot x_2$",MidPoint,align=X-Y),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=2),p=black);
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: I know thanks should be avoided, but still I wanted to warmly thank you. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Hello Charles. The very first one solution which combines the "rectangular" patches is very interesting and allows to deal with more general non orderer data (for rectangular finite elements for example even if the mesh is stored in an appropriate format). Now both solutions are equivalent, juste replace the data by a function.

Answer (score 5):

Please find another solution. Sorry for late, I had another tasks...

Since the data are very well organized it is possible to construct a parametrized Bézier patches surface in the same spirit as the `surface parametrized` asymptote routine. In fact the surface described by a real function over a `box(a,b)` (only on a grid, `f` defined from the box to R) is an adaptation of a Scilab function.

For a surface described by a parametric function `f` over `box(a,b)` the process is the following (`f` takes value in 3D): if `f` depends on `(t,s)` variable, `Dt` a uniform subdivision in `t` with `nu` points, `Ds` a uniform subdivision in `s` with `nv` points. `F` the value of `f` on the grid, `Fx`, `Fy`, `Fz` the `x`, `y`, `z` values. Using the previous routine we construct 3 Bézier parametrized surfaces;  `(Fx,{1,...,nu},{1,...,nv})`, `(Fy,{1,...,nu},{1,...,nv})`, `(Fz,{1,...,nu},{1,...,nv})`. At last we obtain the Bézier parametrized surface `(Fx,Fy,Fz)`. It is a very naive method and in 2D it is well known that you can have some inappropriate behavior (see De Boor). 
If someone has a better parametrized choice (instead of uniform) please let me know.

It is not very difficult to adapt this to your case.

```
// Global Asymptote definitions can be put here.
import three;
import grid3;

usepackage("mathptmx");

// One can globally override the default toolbar settings here:
// settings.toolbar=true;

import graph3;

real xmin=-2, xmax=2;
real ymin=-2, ymax=1.5;
real zmin=-2.5, zmax=2.5;

limits((xmin,ymin,zmin),(xmax,ymax,zmax));

currentprojection=perspective(camera=(1.5,2,2.5));

unitsize(3cm,3cm,2cm);


real linewidth=1.1;
real linewidthprojections=.15;

string filebasename="./data/ForASY_mnl2ippGridBranche3T1_";

bool renderPRC = false;

if(renderPRC) {
  // PRC TRUE
  settings.prc=true;
  settings.embed=true;
}
else {
  // RASTERIZE
  settings.outformat="png";
  settings.prc=false;
  settings.render=3;
}


/////// ORBITS IN 3D, SMOOTH ////////
for (int i=1; i<=50; i=i+2)
  {
string filename1 = filebasename + string(i) + "PartI.dat";
file in1=input(filename1).line().csv();
real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
a1=transpose(a1);

real[] x1=a1[0];
real[] y1=a1[1];
real[] z1=a1[3];

pen orbitpen=.7bp+red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50));
pen projpen=.3bp+red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50))+opacity(0.3);

path3 thepath1 = graph(x1, y1, z1, operator..);
draw(thepath1,orbitpen,currentlight);
  }



//////// SURFACE PART I ////////


triple[][] v=new triple[50][21];


int increment=1;
for (int i=1; i<52-increment; i=i+increment)
  {
string filename1 = filebasename + string(i) + "PartI.dat";
file in1=input(filename1).line().csv();
real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
a1=transpose(a1);
real[] x=a1[0];
real[] y=a1[1];
real[] z=a1[3];
int step=1;
for (int j=0; j<22-step; j=j+step) 
      {
        v[i-1][j]=(x[j],y[j],z[j]);

      }
  }

int nu=50-1;
int nv=21-1;
real[] ipt=sequence(nu+1);
real[] jpt=sequence(nv+1);
real[][] fx=new real[nu+1][nv+1];
real[][] fy=new real[nu+1][nv+1];
real[][] fz=new real[nu+1][nv+1];

splinetype[] usplinetype=Spline;
splinetype[] vsplinetype=Spline;

for(int i=0; i <nu+1; ++i) {
  real ui=i;
  real[] fxi=fx[i];
  real[] fyi=fy[i];
  real[] fzi=fz[i];
  for(int j=0; j < nv+1; ++j) {
    pair z=(ui,j);
    fxi[j]=v[i][j].x;
    fyi[j]=v[i][j].y;
    fzi[j]=v[i][j].z;
  }
}
real[][][] sx=bispline(fx,ipt,jpt);//,usplinetype[0],vsplinetype[0]);
real[][][] sy=bispline(fy,ipt,jpt);//,usplinetype[1],vsplinetype[1]);
real[][][] sz=bispline(fz,ipt,jpt);//,usplinetype[2],vsplinetype[2]);

surface s=surface(sx.length);
s.index=new int[nu][nv];
int k=-1;
for(int i=0; i < nu; ++i) {
  int[] indexi=s.index[i];
  for(int j=0; j < nv; ++j)
    indexi[j]=++k;
}
for(int k=0; k < sx.length; ++k) {
  triple[][] Q=new triple[4][];
  real[][] Px=sx[k];
  real[][] Py=sy[k];
  real[][] Pz=sz[k];
  for(int i=0; i < 4 ; ++i) {
    real[] Pxi=Px[i];
    real[] Pyi=Py[i];
    real[] Pzi=Pz[i];
    Q[i]=new triple[] {(Pxi[0],Pyi[0],Pzi[0]),
                       (Pxi[1],Pyi[1],Pzi[1]),
                       (Pxi[2],Pyi[2],Pzi[2]),
                       (Pxi[3],Pyi[3],Pzi[3])};
  }
  s.s[k]=patch(Q);
}

draw(s,red);
////// CONTOUR OPENING //////

string fileImpactData = "./data/impactData.dat";
file in1=input(fileImpactData).line().csv();
real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
a1=transpose(a1);

real[] x1=a1[0];
real[] y1=a1[1];
real[] z1=a1[3];

pen contourpen=green+1.5bp;

draw(graph(x1,y1,z1,operator--),contourpen,currentlight);

////// PLANES ///////
pen bg=gray(0.9)+opacity(0.2);
draw(surface((xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmin,ymax,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmax,ymax,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmin)--cycle),bg);

////// GRID LINES ///////
pen gridpen=.2bp+gray(0.7);

grid3(XYgrid,Step=1,gridpen);
grid3(YXgrid,Step=.5,gridpen);
grid3(XZgrid,Step=1,gridpen);
grid3(ZXgrid,Step=2,gridpen);
grid3(YZgrid,Step=.5,gridpen);
grid3(ZYgrid,Step=2,gridpen);

// No-go zone
draw((xmax,1,zmin)--(xmin,1,zmin)--(xmin,1,zmax),black+1bp);

xaxis3(Label("$x_1$",MidPoint,align=Y-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
yaxis3(Label("$x_2$",MidPoint,align=X-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=.5),p=black);
zaxis3(Label("$\dot x_2$",MidPoint,align=X-Y),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=2),p=black);
```

The code is not optimized. You obtain the picture. I do not manage the color palette.

[image]

It is possible to have a very short solution (but not very readable).
The "Bézier parametrized" process (50 lines) is replaced by 5 lines.

```
// Global Asymptote definitions can be put here.
import three;
import grid3;
import palette;

usepackage("mathptmx");

// One can globally override the default toolbar settings here:
// settings.toolbar=true;

import graph3;

real xmin=-2, xmax=2;
real ymin=-2, ymax=1.5;
real zmin=-2.5, zmax=2.5;

limits((xmin,ymin,zmin),(xmax,ymax,zmax));

currentprojection=perspective(camera=(1.5,2,2.5));

unitsize(3cm,3cm,2cm);


real linewidth=1.1;
real linewidthprojections=.15;

string filebasename="./data/ForASY_mnl2ippGridBranche3T1_";

bool renderPRC = false;

if(renderPRC) {
  // PRC TRUE
  settings.prc=true;
  settings.embed=true;
}
else {
  // RASTERIZE
  settings.outformat="png";
  settings.prc=false;
  settings.render=3;
}


/////// ORBITS IN 3D, SMOOTH ////////
for (int i=1; i<=50; i=i+2)
  {
string filename1 = filebasename + string(i) + "PartI.dat";
file in1=input(filename1).line().csv();
real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
a1=transpose(a1);

real[] x1=a1[0];
real[] y1=a1[1];
real[] z1=a1[3];

pen orbitpen=.7bp+red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50));
pen projpen=.3bp+red*(1-sqrt(1-i/50))+rgb(0,62/255,91/255)*(sqrt(1-i/50))+opacity(0.3);

path3 thepath1 = graph(x1, y1, z1, operator..);
draw(thepath1,orbitpen,currentlight);
  }



//////// SURFACE PART I ////////


triple[][] v=new triple[50][21];


int increment=1;
for (int i=1; i<52-increment; i=i+increment)
  {
string filename1 = filebasename + string(i) + "PartI.dat";
file in1=input(filename1).line().csv();
real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
a1=transpose(a1);
real[] x=a1[0];
real[] y=a1[1];
real[] z=a1[3];
int step=1;
for (int j=0; j<22-step; j=j+step) 
      {
        v[i-1][j]=(x[j],y[j],z[j]);

      }
  }
triple f (pair t) {
  return(v[round(t.x)][round(t.y)]);
}

surface ns=surface(f,(0,0),(49,20),49,20,Spline);
ns.colors(palette(ns.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(ns,render(merge=true));

////// CONTOUR OPENING //////

string fileImpactData = "./data/impactData.dat";
file in1=input(fileImpactData).line().csv();
real[][] a1=in1.dimension(0,0); // 0 pour dire jusqu'à la fin du fichier
a1=transpose(a1);

real[] x1=a1[0];
real[] y1=a1[1];
real[] z1=a1[3];

pen contourpen=green+1.5bp;

draw(graph(x1,y1,z1,operator--),contourpen,currentlight);

////// PLANES ///////
pen bg=gray(0.9)+opacity(0.2);
draw(surface((xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmin,ymax,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmax)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--cycle),bg);
draw(surface((xmax,ymax,zmin)--(xmax,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymin,zmin)--(xmin,ymax,zmin)--cycle),bg);

////// GRID LINES ///////
pen gridpen=.2bp+gray(0.7);

grid3(XYgrid,Step=1,gridpen);
grid3(YXgrid,Step=.5,gridpen);
grid3(XZgrid,Step=1,gridpen);
grid3(ZXgrid,Step=2,gridpen);
grid3(YZgrid,Step=.5,gridpen);
grid3(ZYgrid,Step=2,gridpen);

// No-go zone
draw((xmax,1,zmin)--(xmin,1,zmin)--(xmin,1,zmax),black+1bp);

xaxis3(Label("$x_1$",MidPoint,align=Y-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=1),p=black);
yaxis3(Label("$x_2$",MidPoint,align=X-Z),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=.5),p=black);
zaxis3(Label("$\dot x_2$",MidPoint,align=X-Y),Bounds(Both,Min),InTicks(Step=2),p=black);
```

A similar picture with a color palette.
[image]

Comment: Sorry for my late comment and thank you for your very efficient solution. I have never used `palette`, but I am not sure if it can easily be parametrized as a function of the file number (rather than z as in `ns.map(zpart)`). Anyway, I used Charles Staat's code as it came first. The computation time to activate navigation in pdf (with `prc`) is the same, as well as the size of the file. Again, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. In fact my goal was only to have the smooth surface and to give some explanations. The `palette` option comes from the asymptote gallery and I missed it from your message.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific reference for the bad behavior of this algorithm? De Boor did a whole lot of stuff.

Comment: You're right. "A pratical guide to spline", revised edition, Springer : chapter 16, Taut Splines, Periodic splines, cardinal splines, pages 277-279 example 19 : choice of parametrization is important (yes it is !). I made some tests a few years ago. It is in relation with the first solution I gave in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231515/draw-a-smooth-surface and the `spline` option : a very bad result.

Answer (score 4):

Consider [this example](http://www.piprime.fr/742/asymptote-using-three_asy-fig0020/). Does this result illustrate what you need?

[image]

As you can see in the following code, the 2-array `P` stores the coordinates and `s` is a surface constructed by `P`. Then `s` is colored by an array of pens.

```
import three;
import palette;

size(12cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(1,1,1.5);
currentlight=(1,0,1);

triple P00=-X-Y+0.5*Z, P03=-X+Y, P33=X+Y, P30=X-Y;

triple[][] P={
  {P00,P00+(-0.5,0.5,-1),P03+(0,-0.5,1),P03},
  {P00+(0.5,-0.5,-1),(-0.5,-0.5,0.5),(-0.5,0.5,-1.5),P03+(0.5,0,1)},
  {P30+(-0.5,0,1),(0.5,-0.5,-1.5),(0.5,0.5,1),P33+(-0.5,0,1)},
  {P30,P30+(0,0.5,1),P33+(0,-0.5,1),P33}
};

surface s=surface(patch(P));
s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Gradient(yellow,red)));
// s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()));

draw(s);
draw(sequence(new path3(int i){
      return s.s[i].external();},s.s.length), bp+orange);

if(!is3D())
  shipout(bbox(Fill(lightgrey)));
```

It looks good. However in
[another example](http://www.piprime.fr/733/asymptote-using-graph3_asy-fig0170/) it warns

> Here we determine the colors of vertexes (vertex shading).
>    Since the PRC output format does not support vertex shading of Bezier surfaces, PRC patches
>    are shaded with the mean of the four vertex colors.

So there is nothing to do with asymptote as long as you want PRC.

Warning: on my computer, OpenGL has a hard time to handle thousands of bezier surfaces. So please test a lot before you present it.

Comment: In the given example, P contains not only the points (4 triples), but three more rows to define the tangents (3*4 triples). The given result is for one quadrangle; if I had to calculate the 12 spline parameters so that the surface is smooth, that'd be extremely tedious...  I'd like Asymptote to calculate the parameters of the smooth surface for me. I know it is not an easy problem (with several possible solutions), but I'm surprised I spent so many hours on this and still see no end to it--not blaming asymptote but my skills. I did not manage to make Charles code work for open surfaces yet.

Comment: @anderstood Sorry I did not study the case carefully. But I saw, in the second link I provide, an construction `surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(pi,2pi),100,Spline);` Doesn't the keyword `Spline` realize your dream?

Comment: no worries, that was not obvious, it took me quite some time to understand what P was. The construction you indicate is similar to that used by Charles Staat (see comments below OP). I tried with that too, but in vain. I think the main reason why I fail is that I don't have an explicit function `f`, but a list of points, so the calculation of the derivatives (to make a smooth surface) is not straightforward.

Comment: @anderstood I had a small experiment that if you send `100` to assign the size of samples, the function `f` is called 101*101 times. That means you can patch your data to make it looks like a function, right?

Comment: Also in asymptote manual there is a declaration `surface surface(triple[][] f, bool[][] cond={});`. Which is followed by ``// return the surface described by a matrix f``.

Comment: partial answer: I get the error `no matching function 'surface(triple[][], bool[][])'` which I hardly understand given it's in the doc: http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/graph3.html.

Comment: (Symbol 1, I don't know how to @ you because of the space in your username...) Concerning your other suggestion, I don't know how to define `f` since `surface.point(uv.x, uv.y);` because doesn't return what I expect (cf comment below OP). I still have an idea: calculate the splines of the _curves_ and reconstruct each quadrangle with the proper parameters, using the technique used in your answer. But that for the least not staightforward!