# asymptote 3d plot with contour on top of surface

Tags: 3d, asymptote, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to plot 3D graph with Asymptote. I used a previous post as [guidance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514901/how-to-draw-3d-surface-plot-from-csv-with-asymptote).

I have well structred X and Y and Z values in 2 files. One with x and y variables and the other file with z matrix. All computations are performed using R. I'm only using Asymptote for plotting.

- Here is xy file with x and y variable (100 rows) in csv format:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rotpeelk9530dsl/xy_new.csv?dl=0
- Here is the z **matrix** for each combination of x and y (100 x 100) in csv format:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwefr4te1dew11c/z_new.csv?dl=0

Below is the Asymptote code that was tried so far:

```
import three;
import grid3;
import graph3;
import palette;

unitsize(5cm,5cm,5cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(18,17,3);

bool renderPRC = true; 

if(renderPRC) { ...
    // PRC TRUE
    settings.prc=true;
    settings.embed=true;
}
else {
    // RASTERIZE
    settings.outformat="png";
    settings.prc=false;
    settings.render=3;
}

file fic =input("xy_new.csv").line().csv(); 
file fic1 =input("z_new.csv").line().csv();

real[][] z=fic1.dimension(0,100);
real[][] a=fic.dimension(0,2);
real [][] b=transpose(a);

real [] xpt,ypt;
xpt = b[1];
ypt = b[0];
real[][] zpt=-z;

surface s=surface(zpt,xpt,ypt,Spline);
s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(s);
```

The output that I get is not a 3D file.

[image]

I'm expecting something like this:

[image]

The above plot was produced using the following `R` function with same x,y and z values:

```
plot3D::persp3D(x = x, y = y, z = -1*z, col="grey87",cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1,
        colkey=FALSE, theta=-30,alpha = 1,zlim=c(-500,-240),ylim=c(0.2,5),
        border = "grey50", ticktype="detailed",scale=T,
        contour=list(levels = -1*c(240,242.09,242.3,242.8,243,244,245,246,247,247.5,247.8),side ="z",col="grey39"),
        xlab="$\\sigma$",ylab="$\\xi$", zlab="Log Likelihood",
        lty=0,expand = 0.7)
```

I have 2 part question:

1. Why is my Asymptote plot not in 3d?
2. How can I draw contour on top of surface plot?

Comment: What else can I do to improve my post? Greatly appreciate any feedback. Thankd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for late, but it is very difficult to have free time and then to contribute on Asymptote question.

Your main problem is `unitsize` and the difference between x, y, z, ranges. It is why you have such a picture.
You then have two possibilitues : modify `unitsize` or use `size3` with `IgnoreAspect` (which avoids automatic scaling). I also add the contour question.

```
import grid3;
import graph3;
import palette;
import contour; 
import x11colors; 
//unitsize(2cm,.002cm,.05cm);
size3(300,300,IgnoreAspect);

currentprojection=orthographic(18,17,3);

currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(-15.2232850051446,-32914.6837071317,892.991504793621),
                               zoom=0.822702474791882);

file fic =input("xy_new.csv").line().csv(); 
file fic1 =input("z_new.csv").line().csv();

real[][] z=fic1.dimension(0,100);
real[][] a=fic.dimension(0,2);
real [][] b=transpose(a);

real [] xpt,ypt;
xpt = b[1];
ypt = b[0];
real[][] zpt=-z;

surface s=surface(zpt,xpt,ypt,Spline);
s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(s);


for (int i=0; i<10 ; ++i)
  { real t = -250+i; 
    guide[][] contours = contour(zpt,(0.2,100),(5,5000),new real[]{t},join=operator ..);
    guide3[][] liftedcontours = lift(new real (real x, real y) {return t;}, contours);
    for(guide3 p:liftedcontours[0]){
      draw(p,blue+1bp);
    }
  }

xaxis3(Label("$x$",.1),Bounds,InTicks);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",0.5),Bounds,InTicks);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",0.5),Bounds,InTicks(beginlabel=false));
```

And then the result[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to respond, ignore aspect ratio is the key. I figured it out last week. One additional question, is there a way to label the conours?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to add colours/legend for a few contours. Do you have an idea of the desired 3D-pictures. In front of the 3D, another possibility is to add a 2D contour with legends...

Comment: Add 2D contour on the side of the picture with labels is preferred.  Label directly on the contour. Thank you.